# Adding Message for empty row in bootstrap table

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I'm working on a Django project but am relatively new to bootstrap and css.
I have a table with books inventory and its looking fine until there are records in them. But when there are no records, I want to display a placeholder "No books added yet."
I've tried multiple ways but I'm unable to do so.
This is my html file:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Author</th>
      <th scope="col">Genre</th>
      <th scope="col">Available</th>
      <th scope="col">Add Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% if books.count > 0 %}
    {% for row in books %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{row.title}}</td>
      <td>{{row.author}}</td>
      <td>{{row.genre}}</td>
      <td>{% if row.available %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{{row.date}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <tr>
      <td>No Books added yet !</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Doing so, the placeholder is just comimg on the first cell:

[image]

How to edit this so this cell shows as a complete row?

Comment: you have to check first before writing <td>{{row.title}}</td><td>{{row.author}}</td>.... if true write all the <td> if not write 1 <td> with colspan  <td colspan="here you write number of columns you habe">{{row.title}}</td>

Comment: Great ! It was that easy, thanks a lot..

Comment: Thanks a ton @yoss, you answer is spot on..

Answer (score 0):

Just add a colspan to your td element with your empty table message